# Visual Studio "Open as a Web Site" context menu option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, contextmenu, webmatrix, explorer

Microsoft WebMatrix comes with an awesome Windows Explorer context menu option that allows you to open a folder as a website project. Are there any extensions or scripts I can use to add a similar option to do the same with Visual Studio?

Comment: Any luck with the answer below?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect. I was simply away for the holidays. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a small project that does just what you're asking for:

> The complete code can be downloaded [here](http://scottonwriting.net/demos/LoadWebsiteFromContextMenu.zip). Once you have the code
>   downloaded and compiled, to add the “Open as Website” option to the
>   Windows Explorer context menu you'll need to run the .reg file
>   included in the download. This adds a registry entry in
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\ that runs the
>   program, passing in the path folder of that was just right-clicked.
>   You will need to customize this .reg file before you run it, putting
>   in the path to the program. You'll also need to specify the path to
>   dump the project files. I chose the folder C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Scott\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2005\Projects\TempWebsiteProjects, but any path should suffice.

Take a look here for the full instructions:  http://scottonwriting.com/sowblog/archive/2005/12/05/163132.aspx